# Select pasted text in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text-2

I'd like to have a keyboard shortcut to paste text in Sublime Text 2 and select the text that I've just pasted in, since I often have to manipulate the block I've just pasted (e.g. changing its indentation level). Is this possible?

Comment: It seems the *Mark* functionality, while appearing promising, does not work in this case, as the mark is moved to the end of the pasted text (i.e. anchors to the right of the cursor).

Comment: If indenting is all you need, maybe *Paste and Indent* works for you?

Comment: @DanielBeck Yes, I use "Paste and Indent", but it's not fool-proof; sometimes I want a different level of indentation than it expects.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can use simple cutting and pasting for this.  In Windows and Linux Ctrl-C will copy the currently selected text, Ctrl-X will cut the currently selected text and Ctrl-V will paste in the current buffer.  In OSX you would use the Cmd button instead of Ctrl.  You can also enable vi bindings in Sublime Text which if you are comfortable with vi will allow you much more control over your buffers and allow you to select which one you want to manipulate.

Comment: The problem is that *after pasting*, the *pasted text* should be *selected* (automatically) to enable further modification.